# Install OpenCL on Ubuntu 14.04 and Nvidia

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I have a nvidia gpu and I need to install opencl as dependency for a library I use. 
I have been searching for a solution for hours.
Here are the steps I made :

1- Download [Intel SDK for OpenCL™ Applications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#sdk)

2- Unpacked the tarball

3- changed the rpm files to deb

```
for f in *.rpm; do
   fakeroot alien --to-deb $f
 done
 for f in *.deb; do
   sudo dpkg -i $f
 done
```

Then, I downloaded OpenCL device query [file](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl) provided by Nvidia by this line

```
g++ -o oclDeviceQuery.cpp -I/opt/intel/opencl-1.2-sdk-6.0.0.1049/include oclDeviceQuery.cpp -lOpenCL
```

It gave me an error in `#include <oclUtils.h>`

```
fatal error: oclUtils.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried to check if the library I need would see OpenCL but it didn't.
I am doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/541114/how-to-make-opencl-work-on-14-10-nvidia-331-89-drivers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you want to use your nVidia GPU, you will need to install the nVida OpenCL runtime, which is part of the GPU driver. You should not need the Intel OpenCL SDK. A simple

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-opencl-dev
```

should install everything you need. Alternatively, download nVidia CUDA 7.5 from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads. This also includes OpenCL.

Comment: What is the procedure if I have the proprietary driver installed instead ? (Not from the packages but fro the nvidia toolkit)